# Glossaries: Abbreviations not appearing from 2nd use onwards

Tags: glossaries

I want two glossaries: 1) Nomenclature 2) Abbreviations

In nomenclature, there are four columns and in abbreviations, there are three.

Everything is working fine except the Abbreviations are not appearing from 2nd use onwards.

What is the problem in the code I am using?

Nomenclature file: INP-00-glossary.tex

content:

```
\newacronym[user1={K}]{T}{\textit{T}}{temperature}
```

Abbreviations file: INP-01-glossary.tex

Content:

```
\newglossaryentry{MC}
{
  name={MC},
  description={Monte Carlo},
  first={\glsentrydesc{MC} (\glsentrytext{MC})}
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,times]{report}


\usepackage{hhline}%double line in table
\usepackage{lipsum,appendix}
%\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}%creates a reference with additional text corresponding to the target's type
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black,          % red,color of internal links
    citecolor=black,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=black,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=black,           % color of external links
    anchorcolor=black
}




\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

%glossaries and acronym
\usepackage[acronym,xindy,sanitize=none,sort=def,toc,
numberline,indexonlyfirst,nomain]{glossaries} %nomain, if you define glossaries in a file, and you use \include{INP-00-glossary}


\newglossary[nlg]{nomenc}{not}{ntn}{Nomenclature}
\newglossary[slg]{abbrev}{sot}{stn}{Abbreviations}



%custom glossary style
\newglossarystyle{long6col}{%  
 % put the glossary in a longtable environment:  
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%  
  {\begin{longtable}{lp{\glsdescwidth}cccp{\glspagelistwidth}}}%  
  {\end{longtable}}%  
 % Set the table’s header:  
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  
  \bfseries Term & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Symbol &  
  \bfseries Units & \bfseries Dimensions & \bfseries Page List  
  \\\endhead}%  
 % No heading between groups:  
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%  
 % Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row optionally numbered:  
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  
    \glsentryitem{##1}% Entry number if required  
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}% Name  
    & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description  
    & \glossentrysymbol{##1}% Symbol  
    & \glsentryuseri{##1}% Units  
    & \glsentryuserii{##1}% Dimensions  
    & ##2% Page list  
    \tabularnewline % end of row  
  }%  
 % Similarly for sub-entries (no sub-entry numbers):  
 \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%  
    % ignoring first argument (sub-level)  
    \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}% Name  
    & \glossentrydesc{##2}% Description  
    & \glossentrysymbol{##2}% Symbol  
    & \glsentryuseri{##2}% Units  
    & \glsentryuserii{##2}% Dimensions  
    & ##3% Page list  
    \tabularnewline % end of row  
  }%  
 % Nothing between groups:  
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%  
}
%END: custom glossary style



%custom glossary1 style
\newglossarystyle{long6col1}{%
% put the glossary in a longtable environment:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
{\begin{longtable}{lp{\glsdescwidth}cccp{\glspagelistwidth}}}%
{\end{longtable}}%
% Set the table’s header:
\renewcommand
*
{\glossaryheader}{%
\bfseries Term & \bfseries Description & &
 & & \bfseries Page List
\\\endhead}%
% No heading between groups:
\renewcommand
*
{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
% Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row optionally numbered:
\renewcommand
*
{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\glsentryitem{##1}% Entry number if required
\glstarget{##1}{##2}% Name
& ##3% Description
& ##4% Symbol
& \glsentryuseri{##1}% Units
& \glsentryuserii{##1}% Dimensions
& ##5% Page list
\\% end of row
}%
% Similarly for sub-entries (no sub-entry numbers):
\renewcommand
*
{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
% ignoring first argument (sub-level)
\glstarget{##2}{##3}% Name
& ##4% Description
& ##5% Symbol
& \glsentryuseri{##2}% Units
& \glsentryuserii{##2}% Dimensions
& ##6% Page list
\\% end of row
}%
% Nothing between groups:
\renewcommand
*
{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}

%

\let\oldgls\gls
\renewcommand{\gls}[1]{%
  \ifglsused{#1}%
    {\glsentrylong{#1}}%
    {\oldgls{#1}}%
}


%END: custom glossary style


\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}%removes dot at end
\glssetwidest{AAAAAAA}% widest name
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}



\makeglossaries

%\loadglsentries[nomenc]{INP-00-glossary}
\let\oldacronymtype\acronymtype
\def\acronymtype{nomenc}
\loadglsentries[nomenc]{INP-00-glossary}
\let\acronymtype\oldacronymtype

\loadglsentries[abbrev]{INP-01-glossary}






\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\printglossary[style=long6col,type=nomenc]
\newpage
\printglossary[style=long6col1,type=abbrev]
\newpage

\gls{MC} used. another \gls{MC}

\gls{T} used , another \gls{T}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix this problem is to remove some unnecessary complexity.

First, change your INP-01-glossary.tex to:

```
\newacronym{MC}{MC}{Monte Carlo}
```

Now the `\newacronym` does use `\newglossaryentry` in the background and you can use `\newglossaryentry` to do this, but as your abbreviations are essentially acronyms, I would simply use `\newacronym`.

Second, remove some code starting with your redefinition of `\gls`. Thats this part:

```
\let\oldgls\gls
\renewcommand{\gls}[1]{%
  \ifglsused{#1}%
    {\oldgls{#1}}%
    {\glsentrylong{#1}}%
}
```

`\gls` works the way you want it too, and will allow you to use other glossary macros without any inconsistencies.

Additionally, you can remove your `\acronymtype` modifications making this part:

```
\let\oldacronymtype\acronymtype
\def\acronymtype{nomenc}
\loadglsentries[nomenc]{INP-00-glossary}
\let\acronymtype\oldacronymtype
```

simply:

```
\loadglsentries[nomenc]{INP-00-glossary}
```

With this change you also need to remove the `acronym` option from the glossaries package options or when you run makeglossaries you will get an error.

---

All combined the MWE for your document is now:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,times]{report}
\usepackage{hhline}%double line in table
\usepackage{lipsum,appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black,          % red,color of internal links
    citecolor=black,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=black,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=black,           % color of external links
    anchorcolor=black
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[xindy,sanitize=none,sort=def,toc,
numberline,indexonlyfirst,nomain]{glossaries}

\newglossary[nlg]{nomenc}{not}{ntn}{Nomenclature}
\newglossary[slg]{abbrev}{sot}{stn}{Abbreviations}

%custom glossary style
\newglossarystyle{long6col}{%
 % put the glossary in a longtable environment:
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {\begin{longtable}{lp{\glsdescwidth}cccp{\glspagelistwidth}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
 % Set the table’s header:
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
  \bfseries Term & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Symbol &
  \bfseries Units & \bfseries Dimensions & \bfseries Page List
  \\\endhead}%
 % No heading between groups:
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
 % Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row optionally numbered:
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}% Entry number if required
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}% Name
    & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
    & \glossentrysymbol{##1}% Symbol
    & \glsentryuseri{##1}% Units
    & \glsentryuserii{##1}% Dimensions
    & ##2% Page list
    \tabularnewline % end of row
  }%
 % Similarly for sub-entries (no sub-entry numbers):
 \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
    % ignoring first argument (sub-level)
    \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}% Name
    & \glossentrydesc{##2}% Description
    & \glossentrysymbol{##2}% Symbol
    & \glsentryuseri{##2}% Units
    & \glsentryuserii{##2}% Dimensions
    & ##3% Page list
    \tabularnewline % end of row
  }%
 % Nothing between groups:
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}
%END: custom glossary style



%custom glossary1 style
\newglossarystyle{long6col1}{%
% put the glossary in a longtable environment:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
{\begin{longtable}{lp{\glsdescwidth}cccp{\glspagelistwidth}}}%
{\end{longtable}}%
% Set the table’s header:
\renewcommand
*
{\glossaryheader}{%
\bfseries Term & \bfseries Description & &
 & & \bfseries Page List
\\\endhead}%
% No heading between groups:
\renewcommand
*
{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
% Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row optionally numbered:
\renewcommand
*
{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\glsentryitem{##1}% Entry number if required
\glstarget{##1}{##2}% Name
& ##3% Description
& ##4% Symbol
& \glsentryuseri{##1}% Units
& \glsentryuserii{##1}% Dimensions
& ##5% Page list
\\% end of row
}%
% Similarly for sub-entries (no sub-entry numbers):
\renewcommand
*
{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
% ignoring first argument (sub-level)
\glstarget{##2}{##3}% Name
& ##4% Description
& ##5% Symbol
& \glsentryuseri{##2}% Units
& \glsentryuserii{##2}% Dimensions
& ##6% Page list
\\% end of row
}%
% Nothing between groups:
\renewcommand
*
{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}

%

%END: custom glossary style

\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}%removes dot at end
\glssetwidest{AAAAAAA}% widest name
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries[nomenc]{INP-00-glossary}
\loadglsentries[abbrev]{INP-01-glossary}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\printglossary[style=long6col,type=nomenc]
\newpage
\printglossary[style=long6col1,type=abbrev]
\newpage

\gls{MC} used. another \gls{MC}

\gls{T} used , another \gls{T}

\end{document}
```

Producing (for the 3rd page):

[image: mwe output]